# What does a single quote inside a C# date time format mean?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, .net-core, datetime-format

We have e.g. this constant in C#:

```
System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo.SortableDateTimePattern
```

It has this value:

```
"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss"
```

I do use it in the `ParseExact` function and then `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` works as well.

I cannot figure out what the single quotes are for.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

It's a [literal string delimiter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#Literals).

Anything between the single quotes is interpreted as a literal character, and will not be interpreted as a custom format string.

They are equivalent to escaping using a backslash: `dd'T'HH` is the same as `dd\THH`.

In your string `yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss`, the quotes are unnecessary around the `-` and `T`, as those are not custom format strings, and so will always be interpreted as string literals. However `:` [is a format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#timeSeparator), which evaluates to a time separator that's suitable for the current culture. Quoting it as `':'` means that the literal character `:` will always be used, regardless of the current culture.

Answer (score 2):

It's useful to know that this is the same format used by the Windows [**GetDateFormat**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/datetimeapi/nf-datetimeapi-getdateformata) function. You use apostrophe's to indicate some literal you want inserted into the resulting string.

More documentation of the string formatting codes can be found on:

- [Day, Month, Year, and Era Format Pictures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/day--month--year--and-era-format-pictures)

In your string it is indiating that it *literally* wants to add hyphens, colons, and the **T** characters:

> yyyy **`'-'`** MM **`'-'`** dd **`'T'`** HH **`':'`** mm **`':'`** ss

In general you don't want to construct dates/times with **literally** a hyphens (`-`) or colons (`:`), or even slashes (`/`). Because those are wrong for cultures that don't use slashes and colons to construct dates/times:

- 10/22/2019 10∶19∶54 ᴀᴍ
- 2019. 10. 22. 10:19:54
- 2019.10.22 10:19:54
- 2019-10-22 10.19.54
- 2019-10-22 10:19:54
- 2019-10-22 10:19:54 AM
- 2019-10-22 ཆུ་ཚོད་10:19:54 སྔ་ཆ་
- 2019-10-22 오전 10:19:54
- 22. 10. 2019 10:19:54
- 22. 10. 2019. 10:19:54
- 22.10.19 10:19:54
- 22.10.19 ý. 10:19:54
- 22.10.2019 10.19.54
- 22.10.2019 10:19:54
- 22.10.2019 10:19:54 p.d.
- 22.10.2019 г. 10:19:54
- 22.10.2019. 10:19:54
- 22-10-19 10.19.54
- 22-10-19 10.19.54 AM
- 22-10-19 10:19:54
- 22-10-19 ਸਵੇਰ 10:19:54
- 22-10-2019 10:19:54
- 22-10-2019 ৰাতিপু 10:19:54
- 22-окт. 19 10:19:54
- 23/02/41 10:19:54 ص
- 30/07/1398 10:19:54 ق.ظ

What you would want to do, if you want to indicate:

- *"here is where you should put the date separator"*
- *"here is where you should put the time separator"*

Is use the special:

- *date separator replacement character* (/)
- *time separator replacement character* (:)

And construct a format such as:

> dd/yyyy/MM ss:HH:mm

I don't know what business need one might have to show a date as:

- 22/2019/10 37:10:24
- 22-2019-10 37∶10∶24
- 22//2019//10 37::10::24
- 22. 2019. 10 37∶10∶24

But this way the localizer will insert the culture's correct date and time separators.

Whereas if you *literally* asked for `/`, `-`, or `:`:

- dd `'/'` yyyy `'/'` MM ss `':'` HH `':'` mm

You will literally get:

- 22/2019/10 37:10:24

rather than:

- 22-2019-10 37∶10∶24

Comment: I don't think .NET's date and time format strings are identical to `GetDateFormat`. Similar perhaps, but for example the meaning of `yyyyy` is different. Given that this question is getting a remarkable amount of attention, and it's about C#/, I suggest correcting this statement and linking to the .NET docs instead.