# Is there a way to exclude a character from the date string while using DateTime.ParseExact?

Tags: c#

I have a bunch of strings with dates in Dutch that look like this:

```
string date =  "5 juli 2011 om 09:29";
```

I'm trying to parse it like this:

```
string format = "dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm";
CultureInfo provider = new CultureInfo("nl-NL");
var PublishedOn = DateTime.ParseExact(date, format, provider);
```

It doesn't work because of the word "om" (which means "at" in Dutch).

I can't use a method to split string before parsing or something like that, because the code is a part of a larger scraper that takes a format string from config, so it should stay generic. I can't put a method or some other logic that manipulates the string in the scraper code because it won't work for other websites anymore. I should be able to just provide a format string and parse the date with it.

Is there a way to exclude the "om" from the date string with format? Maybe with some regex expression in the format or something like that?

I couldn't find anything.

UPDATE: solution is just to use:

```
string format = "dd MMMM yyyy 'om' HH:mm";
```

Comment: Put text to be taken literally in single quotes in the format string: `'om'`.

Comment: Tried that already, didn't work. :(

Comment: Oh no wait it did just now! I think I overworked the format string and something else didn't work before when I tried 'om' lol.

Comment: Yes it does. I've already accepted the answer.

Comment: @charlieface thanks, couldn't find that. The title doesn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want text to be taken literally in a string-to-be-parsed, enclose it in single quotes:

```
string format = "dd MMMM yyyy 'om' HH:mm";
```

See also [What does a single quote inside a C# date time format mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58487644/what-does-a-single-quote-inside-a-c-sharp-date-time-format-mean).